# fiddler overall elapsed time units

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler, what's the units on the Overall Elapsed time? Is this 0.904s?

[image: fiddler statistics page]

Comment: I'm guessing <Hour>:<Minutes>:<Seconds>.<Miliseconds> as in the timestamps above.

Comment: Look at the request time stamps above the `Overall Elapsed` row, the requests was finished in less than a second: 19:08:10 - 19:08:11 (hh:mm:ss).